# How to load the face feature (as np.ndarray) from txt file fastly

Tags: python, performance, numpy, io, face-recognition

I have a face feature dataset stored in a .txt file. Each record has an image name and a 512d feature vector. The format of each line is shown as follows:

```
img_id.jpg 0.0637221 0.0835939 0.0283522 -0.0266797 0.0502897 -0.0108895 ... -0.0266797 0.0502897
```

Each feature should be loaded in a numpy matrix like:

```
[
  [512d-feature],
  [512d-feature],
  ...
  [512d-feature]
]
```

I have tried to load the feature by for-loop, but it seems that the maximum loading speed is ~5000 record/second. However, the total dataset has nearly 10 million records. It would cost nearly 30 minutes to load the feature.

```py
for line in tqdm(content):
    ...
    # load feature
    feature = line.strip().split()[1:]
    feature = [float(i) for i in feature]
    feat_matrix[index] = feature
```

I was wondering that is there a fast way to load the feature in order to reduce the time-consuming? Like using numpy builtin methods, multi-threading, or parallelly loading?

Comment: Have you tried `np.loadtxt('your_feature_data', usecols=range(1,513))`?

Comment: Or with pandas: `df = pd.read_csv('your_feature_data', sep=' ', header=None, usecols=range(1,513))` speeds up loading by 3x on a google colab instance.

Comment: Some benchmarks with a dataset of 20000x512 columns: `for loop: 5.51s, np.loadtxt: 9.62s, pd.read_csv: 2.33s`. `np.loadtxt` seems not to be an option.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thanks a lot! I would try pandas later 